# Incompatibility hyperref enumitem

Tags: hyperref, captions, enumitem

With an inline enumeration in the caption, autoref does not pick up the correct kind (figure) but uses `item` instead.

Is there a workaround?

test.aux file:

```
\newlabel{figure:foo}{{1}{1}{}{Item.2}{}}
```

test.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{(\alph*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
figure-content
\caption[]{figure-caption \begin{enumerate*}\item 1\item2\end{enumerate*}}
\label{figure:foo}
\end{figure}

\autoref{figure:foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you load hyperref after enumitem?

Comment: Did not change anything for me. Nevertheless, I should have tried that also before..

Comment: put the label inside the caption before the enumerate: `\caption[]{figure-caption\label{figure:foo} \begin{enumerate*}...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (without [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)), there's only one thing to keep track of when it comes to setting `\label`s - a number. And, since number changes (via `\stepcounter`, `\refstepcounter`, `\addtocounter` and `\setcounter`) are *global*, one would think that placing a `\label` shortly after a counter will capture the appropriate number for `\ref`erencing. However, it's not the actual number that is capture, but it's representation (which could be different; for example `\thesection` is often `<chapter>.<section>` or technically `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`). This representation is captured in a macro `\@currentlabel` and is stored *locally*. You can see this by means of the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter% Just for this example

\setcounter{figure}{5}% Just for this example

Figure counter and current label (1): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel

\begin{figure}[h]
  Figure counter and current label (2): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel
  \caption{A figure}
  Figure counter and current label (3): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel
\end{figure}

Figure counter and current label (4): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel

\end{document}
```

Note how the figure counter's value changes from (1) through (4), even though it's set in a group at (2) and (3) (the `figure` environment). However, the only time you capture the correct number for a `\label` is *after* `\caption`, but *before* the local group is terminated (here the `figure` environment, again).

This confirms the "requirement" to have a `\label` close to where the appropriate counter is stepped, especially when working with groups (like floats or lists).

With `hyperref`, however, there's an additional component that is stored with every `\label` - the *hyperlink anchor* (technically `\@currentHref`). This anchor acts in the same way as `\@currentlabel`. That is, it's is a macro that is updated with every appropriate `\refstepcounter`. One change though is that `hyperref` updates `\@currentHref` *globally*; it therefore survives the scope of the current group. An expansion of the above MWE shows this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter% Just for this example

\setcounter{figure}{5}% Just for this example

Figure counter, current label and anchor name (1): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel~/~\@currentHref

\begin{figure}[h]
  Figure counter, current label and anchor name (2): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel~/~\@currentHref
  \caption{A figure}
  Figure counter, current label and anchor name (3): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel~/~\@currentHref
\end{figure}

Figure counter, current label and anchor name (4): \thefigure~/~\@currentlabel~/~\@currentHref

\end{document}
```

Note how at position (3) both `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentHref` have correctly-updated values pointing to the figure. However, immediately outside that group, `\@currentlabel` is lost, while `\@currentHref` persists (due to it's *global* nature).

To get around all this, it's best to place your `\label` as close to the appropriate counter change as possible, especially when using `hyperref` in order to avoid confusion with anchors pointing to incorrect content. Your example, with a `\label` *within* the `\caption` - somewhere before the internal `enumerate*` - is updated below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{(\alph*)}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764
\usepackage{hyperref}% Load hyperref last

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[]{\label{fig:foo1}figure-caption \begin{enumerate*}\item 1\item2\end{enumerate*}}
  \label{fig:foo2}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:foo1}

\autoref{fig:foo2}

\end{document}
```

`fig:foo1` provides the correct anchor name and therefore the correct interpretation via `\autoref`, while `fig:foo2` (posted after a *global* change of `\@currentHref` within `enumerate*`) doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the presented problem. I am however using the cas-sc class where the problem is a bit more tricky apparently and asked another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672958/incompatibility-cas-sc-with-hyperref-and-enumitem).