# Incompatibility cas-sc with hyperref and enumitem?

Tags: hyperref, enumitem, els-cas

In another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672949/incompatibility-hyperref-enumitem) I asked about a potential incompatibility between `enumitem` and `hyperref` appearing when using inline enumerations in captions of figures that are then referenced.
The correct answer there seems that I need to load enumitem before hyperref and put the label at the beginning of the caption.

However, in my actual document I am using the [`cas-sc` class of Elsevier](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates), which loads `hyperref` in the `cas-sc` class (and appears to not load `enumitem`).

To ensure that `enumitem` is loaded before `hyperref`, I have patched the `cas-sc` class by adding the line `\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}` after `\LoadClass{article}` is executed.

To my surprise, the solution mentioned in the other question does not work here. The `autoref` still shows "item" instead of "figure".
So I assume that `cas-sc` somehow counters my attempt.

I would be happy if someone could have a look here as well.

#### File `test.aux`

```
\newlabel{figure:foo1}{{1}{1}{}{Item.2}{}}
\newlabel{figure:foo2}{{1}{1}{}{Item.4}{}}
```

#### File `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage[]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
figure-content
\caption[]{\label{figure:foo1}figure-caption \begin{enumerate*}\item 1\item2\end{enumerate*}}
\label{figure:foo2}
\end{figure}

\autoref{figure:foo1}
\autoref{figure:foo2}

\end{document}
```

#### Patched file `cas-sc.sty`

```
%%
%% This is file `cas-dc.cls'.
%%
%% This file is part of the 'CAS Bundle'.
%% ......................................
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'CAS Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 

%% $Id: cas-sc.cls 66 2021-05-11 14:17:42Z rishi $

 \def\RCSfile{cas-sc}%
 \def\RCSversion{2.3}%
 \def\RCSdate{2023/01/25}%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{\RCSfile}[\RCSdate, \RCSversion: Formatting class
   for CAS single column articles]
%
\def\ABD{\AtBeginDocument}
%
% switches
% 
\newif\iflongmktitle    \longmktitlefalse
\newif\ifdc             \global\dcfalse
\newif\ifsc             \global\sctrue
\newif\ifcasreviewlayout  \global\casreviewlayoutfalse
\newif\ifcasfinallayout   \global\casfinallayoutfalse

\newcounter{blind}
\setcounter{blind}{0}

\def\blstr#1{\gdef\@blstr{#1}}
\def\@blstr{1}
\newdimen\@bls
\@bls=\baselineskip

\DeclareOption{singleblind}{\setcounter{blind}{1}}
\DeclareOption{doubleblind}{\setcounter{blind}{2}}
\DeclareOption{longmktitle}{\global\longmktitletrue}
\DeclareOption{final}{\global\casfinallayouttrue}
\DeclareOption{review}{\global\casreviewlayouttrue}

\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,10pt,oneside,fleqn}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\RequirePackage{expl3,xparse}
\@ifundefined{regex_match:nnTF}{\RequirePackage{l3regex}}{}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,array,colortbl,dcolumn,stfloats}
\RequirePackage{xspace,xstring,footmisc}
\RequirePackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\colorlet{scolor}{black}
\colorlet{hscolor}{DarkSlateGrey}
\hypersetup{%
  pdfcreator={LaTeX3; cas-sc.cls; hyperref.sty},
  pdfproducer={pdfTeX;},
  linkcolor={hscolor},
  urlcolor={hscolor},
  citecolor={hscolor},
  filecolor={hscolor},
  menucolor={hscolor},
}
% \AtEndDocument{\hypersetup
%   {pdftitle={\csuse{__short_title:}},
%   pdfauthor={\csuse{__short_authors:}}}}
 
 \let\comma\@empty
\let\tnotesep\@empty
\let\@title\@empty
%
% Load Common items
%

\RequirePackage{cas-common}

%
% Specific to Single Column
%
\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \maketitle {}
{
  \ifbool { usecasgrabsbox }
    { 
      \setcounter{page}{0}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \unvbox\casgrabsbox  
    } { }  
  \pagebreak  
  \ifbool { usecashlsbox }
    { 
      \setcounter{page}{0}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \unvbox\casauhlbox
    } { }    
  \pagebreak  
  \thispagestyle{first}
  \ifbool{longmktitle}
  {
    \ifnum\theblind>0\relax
        \LongMaketitleBox[blind]
    \else
        \LongMaketitleBox
    \fi
    \ProcessLongTitleBox
  }
  {
    \ifnum\theblind>0\relax
        \MaketitleBox[blind]
    \else
        \MaketitleBox
    \fi
    \printFirstPageNotes
  }
  \normalcolor \normalfont
  \setcounter{footnote}{\int_use:N \g_stm_fnote_int}
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
  \gdef\@pdfauthor{\infoauthors}
  \gdef\@pdfsubject{Complex ~STM ~Content}
  \ifbool{casreviewlayout}{\doublespacing}{}
}

%
% Fonts
%
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\file_if_exist:nTF { stix.sty }
{
  \file_if_exist:nTF { charis.sty }
  {
    \RequirePackage[notext]{stix} 
    \RequirePackage{charis}
  }
  { \RequirePackage{stix} }
}
{
  \iow_term:x {  *********************************************************** }
  \iow_term:x { ~Stix ~ and ~ Charis~ fonts ~ are ~ not ~ available ~ }
  \iow_term:x { ~ in ~TeX~system.~Hence~CMR~ fonts~ are ~ used. }
  \iow_term:x {  *********************************************************** }
}

\file_if_exist:nTF { inconsolata }
{ \RequirePackage[scaled=.85]{inconsolata} }
{ \tex_gdef:D \ttdefault { cmtt } }

\ifbool{casreviewlayout}{\RequirePackage{setspace}}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%
% Page geometry
%

\usepackage[%
  paperwidth=192mm,
  paperheight=262mm,
%  vmargin={12.4mm,11.5mm},
  vmargin={19mm,19mm},
  hmargin={13.7mm,13.7mm},
  headsep=12pt,
  footskip=12pt,
]{geometry}


\endinput
  
%
% End of class 'cas-sc'
%
```

Comment: well the class is doing lots of redefinitions ... with a current latex you can disable the anchors from the enumerate locally `\LinkTargetOff\begin{enumerate*}` then it will not longer interfere.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use that for now. Luckily I do not have so many enumerations in captions :)